# jquery turn off uniform plugin

Tags: javascript, jquery, uniform

Uniform is a jQuery plugin for styling forms. In my application I am using it and I have to turn off uniform and turn it on again, I mean I need to restart it.

To turn on functionality of uniform on some of form elements following is to be done `$("select, input, button, textarea").uniform();`

Now I need to turn it off, I mean I want to have a functionality to rollback and bring back the old looks.

Can it be done? Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can restore the original look (and unbind all the event handlers as well) by `uniform` itself: just use its [restore](https://github.com/pixelmatrix/uniform/blob/master/jquery.uniform.js#L661) method. Like this:

```
$.uniform.restore();
```

This method also can be called on the collection of elements.